# jQuery AJAX replacing words in returned data sometimes not working correct

Tags: jquery, ajax, replace

I need to replace some words from returned AJAX data. I do it this way:

```
function loadfile(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'donachrichten.php',
        data: {mach: "loadfile", kontaktfile: kontaktfile},
        success: function(data){
                var kontent = data;

                var user1 = $(".user1").attr("id");
                var user2 = $(".user2").attr("id");
                var profilpic1 = $(".profilpic1").attr("id");
                var profilpic2 = $(".profilpic2").attr("id");

                var data1 = kontent.replace(new RegExp(user1, "g"), profilpic1);
                var data2 = data1.replace(new RegExp(user2, "g"), profilpic2);
                $("#chatnow").html(data2);
        }
    });
}
```

70% of the case it works fine, but in 30% the `chatnow` div is full of `undefinedundefined`....

What could be the problem here?

**EDIT:**

This is what is called before loadfile:

```
function selectkontakt(z){
    $("#loadnew").empty();
    $("#loadold").empty();
    kontaktfile = $(z).attr('id');
    kontakte(); // the user1/user2 and profilpic1/profilpic2 classes are comming from here, also though AJAX
    loadfile();
    $("#textarea").show();
    $('#usermsg').focus();
}
```

So I guess it's just a bad timing, is there a way I could fix the timing?

Answer (score 0):

it may due to the id or element not present. if you are using ajax to load that user element. use this function after that element load/ajax success.

Comment: If you use ajax method to load $(".user1").attr("id"); 
these elements you can call loadfile(); function in the ajax success function of  kontakte();

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

```
function selectkontakt(z){
    $("#loadnew").empty();
    $("#loadold").empty();
    kontaktfile = $(z).attr('id');
    kontakte();
    loadfile().done(kontakte); // HERE
    $("#textarea").show();
    $('#usermsg').focus();
}
```

So the timing can't be broken any more :)